# How to increment a value on a button click in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask

Another query on a JQuery function as a newbie in this. With the help of you guys I was able to modify the code to return the corresponding value from an input tag.
The problem that I am facing now is that on the Add button click I want the `<p class="item-quantity">0</p>` to display the value returned by the JQuery `.get()` in the corresponding row.

Here's my HTML:

```
            {% for item in menu_category %}
            <tr class="item">
              <td><p class="item-name">{{item.item_Name}}</p></td>
              <td><p class="item-price">{{item.item_Price}}</p></td>
              <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary add-item" data-name="{{item.item_Name}}" data-price="{{item.item_Price}}" data-id="{{item.item_Id}}">+</button>
              </td>
              <td><p class="item-quantity">0</p></td>
              <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary remove-item" data-name="{{item.item_Name}}" data-price="{{item.item_Price}}" data-id="{{item.item_Id}}">-</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

And my function:

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
      $('.add-item').on('click', function() {
        $.get('{{ url_for("func_add_to_cart") }}', 
        {
          item_id: $(this).attr("data-id"),
        },
        function(data) {
          $(this).parents().find(".item-quantity").html(data);
        });
        return false;
      });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Simply write -> `$(this).closest(".item").find("p.item-quantity").html(data);`

Comment: Hi @Swati I tried this but it is still returning undefined.

Comment: yes i got why store `$(this)` in some variable before ajax call and then use it . i.e : `var selector =$(this);` and use it like `selector.closest(".item").find("p.item-quantity").html(data);`